# Output warning based on expression result

Tags: python, selenium, expression, warnings, pytest

I'm trying to output warnings in my pytest setup based on the result of an expression. I'm essentially trying to mirror an assert statement **without it stopping my code** while not having to manually format the warning message to mimic the each expression.

For example, I want to make this:

```
test_variable = 5
assert test_variable == 10

# Output:
AssertionError: assert 5 == 10
```

into a simpler version of this:

```
test_variable = 5
if test_variable != 10:
    warnings.warn(f"{test_variable} != 10") # Manually format the output.

# Output:
UserWarning: 5 != 10
```

I couldn't find anything in the [warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) module for Python on how to output a warning based on a false expression.

Any ideas on how to simplify the warnings output so I don't have to format for every check I want to perform a check in my tests?

Comment: `assert` statements don't normally come with convenient messages like that. That's pytest implicitly rewriting your code. Also, if you're putting this in your tests, the tests are going to *pass* even though things went wrong.

Comment: In this case I want the tests to pass, but with warnings. (Pytest supports this). Does Python have a way to output a warning based on a false expression? I'm pretty much just looking for the cleanest approach.

Comment: You can wrap the warning emit into a function and call it where necessary, like e.g. `compare(test_variable, 10, msg='')`.

Answer (score 0):

pytest uses python's assertion. 
You can add a string after assert statement to generate the warning.

```
assert my_var == 10 , "Value of my_var: {} is not equal to 10".format(my_var)
```

It will print this if my_var is 5:

`Value of my_var: 5 is not equal to 10`